# Show that there are exactly $\aleph_1$ nonisomorphic countable well orderings.

Tags: set-theory

Show that there are exactly $\aleph_1$ nonisomorphic countable well orderings.

I used the continuum hypothesis to show that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$ and then i applied $|\mathbb{R}| = 2^{\aleph_0}$ to get $|\mathbb{R}| = \aleph_1$. Then $\aleph_1$ is equal to the cardinality of all real numbers. As $\aleph_1$ is equal to $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1$ is a well ordered set, so is $\aleph_1$. Then I assumed that $\aleph_1$ is a countable well ordering with the cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$.

My teacher told me that I shall not use the continuum hypothesis here, because it was not told to use it.

I am not sure if I have done anything correct, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please search the site before posting your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You know every well ordering is isomorphic to an ordinal. Since $\aleph_1$ is the least uncountable you can deduce that the isomorphism types of countable well orders are exactly the ordinals $< \aleph_1$ (and $>\aleph_0$ if you are intending countable as "of cardinality $\aleph_0$" thus willing to exclude finite well orders).

Now recall that by construction (I'm assuming you construed ordinals as von Neumann ordinals), for every ordinal $\gamma$ you have $\{\alpha \in \mathrm{On}: \alpha <\gamma\} = \gamma$.

If you are intending "countable" in the strong sense, then you may need to note that subtracting a set of cardinality $\aleph_0$ to one of cardinality $\aleph_1$ you get a set of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixing it